# How to set the Content-Transfer-Encoding in python

Tags: python-3.x, email

Some users are having the content transfer encoding type set as base64.  How do I set the Content-Transfer-Encoding manually.

```
  import smtplib
  from email.message import EmailMessage
  from email.encoders import encode_7or8bit

  msg = EmailMessage()
  msg.set_content(message,subtype='html')
  #msg.set_charset('UTF-8')
  msg['Subject'] ="your order is {} at {}".format(order_id,today_is)
  msg['From'] = 'email@gmail.com'
  msg['To'] = 'toemail@gmail.com'
  encode_7or8bit(msg)
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
 ValueError: There may be at most 1 Content-Transfer-Encoding headers in a message
```

If I move `encode_7or8bit(msg)` above `msg.set_content` it works, but I don't think the content is being set.  Should I send something into `set_content`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage()
msg.set_content(message,subtype='html',charset='utf-8',cte='7bit')
msg['Subject'] ="your order is {} at {}".format(order_id,today_is)
msg['From'] = 'email@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'toemail@gmail.com'
```

On `msg.set_content()` I have to send in the cte.
[Python 3 Email Content Encoding Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.contentmanager.html#email.contentmanager.ContentManager.set_content)

Answer (score 1):

To force a particular MIME Content-Transfer-Encoding for an email part using  [EmailMessage from the Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#module-email.message) use the **cte=** argument in [**set_content()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.contentmanager.html#email.contentmanager.set_content):

```py
from email.message import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage()
msg.set_content(message,subtype='html', charset='utf-8', cte='quoted-printable')
#        The cte= option is where you force the encoding ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
msg['Subject'] ="your order is {} at {}".format(order_id, today_is)
msg['From'] = 'email@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'toemail@gmail.com'
```

### Recommendation: Do not set cte= in set_content()

For string email content Python's [set_content(msg, <'str'>, subtype="plain", charset='utf-8', cte=None, ...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.contentmanager.html#email.contentmanager.set_content) automatically detects the most compact ***safe*** encoding for the string data, encodes it, and sets the matching "Content-Transfer-Encoding" header automatically.

If you do have to set it, I strongly recommend you only choose either **cte="quoted-printable"** or **cte="base64"**, and not **7bit**, **8bit** or **binary**. Choosing **7bit**, **8bit** or **binary** in Python will fail with a **ValueError** if the content cannot be encoded, while **quoted-printable** or **base64** will always work.

*Worse, as the success or failure now depends on the content of the email, debugging will be very difficult - imagine one out of every 100 emails failing!*

### Pros and Cons of the Encodings

- **quoted-printable**

  - Good for text with an occasional byte >127. E.g. the odd emoji, an occasional single and multi-byte foreign characters, any newlines, etc.
  - Inefficient but OK for lots of bytes >127. As it converts each >127 bytes into a 3 byte sequence, beginning with = and the ASCII hex value of the byte, effectively triples your data size. Nowadays size probably doesn't matter except for file attachments
  - OK for long lines, transparently soft-breaks them for safe SMTP transmission
  - Somewhat human readable if the input was mostly western UTF-8/ASCII text to begin with. For example **hôpital** -> **h=C3=B4pital** as **ô** is two bytes long in UTF-8.
- **base64**

  - Good for mostly multi-byte characters or binary data
  - OK for long lines, linebreaks are encoded along with everything else and the encoder limits its output line length for safe SMTP transmission
  - More efficient for mostly binary data, but bad for simple text. Breaks the byte string into 3 byte chunks and encodes them using 4 bytes
  - Transparently breaks and reconstructs long lines for safe SMTP transmission
  - Not at all human readable. For example **hôpital** -> **aMO0cGl0YWw=**

### Background

Email, in this case specifically SMTP, is a very old standard that only supported 7bit ASCII text, a maximum line length, and the end-of-line CR-LF code is reserved to signal the end of the SMTP command. These limits meant you could program and run an SMTP server on 8-bit mainframe-type computers with a few kilobytes of memory. One only had to fit the current line in the RAM with enough space to process it.

So for the old **7bit** encoding no character >127 is allowed, for **8bit** encoding >127 is allowed, but for both too long a line is forbidden & CR-LF is reserved for ending the SMTP instruction. It is very hard to guarantee arbitrary binary data will never accidentally have one+ sequences matching the ASCII CR-LF, and to ensure that the data fits inside the max line length.

Most SMTP servers are 8bit clean and have no line length restriction but not all. Additionally, most mail servers and email clients will assume text/plain is UTF-8 encoded and try to send/decode things anyway, etc. but some do not. So don't mess with it, let Python make the optimal choice for you.

Comment: This is potentially helpful information, but makes no attempt to answer the question of "how to set the Content-Transfer-Encoding"

Comment: Edited to answer the question - got caught up in the reasons behind it and missed the forest for the trees, my mistake.